# What is the "thisimage" in the rerere directory?

Tags: git, git-rerere

The preimage is the result of merging the old and new files, I get that. The postimage is the way the conflict was resolved, I get that.

But what is thisimage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained by bitbucket.org:

> “thisimage” is a bookkeeping mechanism rerere uses during a resolution.  It’s possible an unlucky file can have many conflicts, which will all be within this directory.  “thisimage” is the one most recently being worked through.

> Now, when rerere sees a conflict for file.txt, it looks in the corresponding rr-cache dir, find the “preimage” that matches “thisimage” and changes the file in the working directory to match “postimage.”

https://bitbucket.org/blog/resolving-conflicts-with-git-rerere

Comment: Just wanted to leave this quote here because this unanswered question was the first result in my search engine.